# What will happen to my old pull requests if I split a subtree off my main repo and create a new repo?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-subtree, git-rewrite-history

I have a large codebase which I am evaluating a strategy to split certain sections off into smaller repositories. Using git subtree split, I am able to separate out the directories I want & the commit history seems intact.

That being said, assuming I move forward with this approach, what will happen to my old pull requests (which included code from the detached directories) in Github?

Will they still show references to the old code or will the changes only reference the code that is still in the original codebase?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The essence of a pull request is a hash ID within a repository. What will happen to your hash IDs and your existing repository? That tells you the answer to what happens to your pull requests.

Comment: A pull request is nothing more and nothing less than a branch. You can even add a line like: `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`. Trying to merge a pull request is just like merging a branch, with the usual conflict resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new created repo from `git subtree split` will **only contains the commits that you make changes in the specified directories**.

Assume the original git repo file structure as below:

```
Root
|___ file1      
|___ file2
|___ subfolder/
         |___ file3
         |___ file4
```

And the original commit history as:

```
*   8cb09fb (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'dev' into matser
|\
| * e1e054c (dev) change file2 for fourth time merge
* | 6e8ee57 change file3 for fourth time merge
* |   ebdfb0b Merge branch 'dev' into master
|\ \
| |/
| * 5d93766 change file2 for thrid time merge
* | b95668a change file1 for thrid time merge
* |   09ca222 Merge branch 'dev' into matser
|\ \
| |/
| * d3dc890 change file3 for second time merge
* | 5818123 change file1 for second time merge
* |   cb39f04 Merge branch 'dev' into master
|\ \
| |/
| * 4dc4aaa change file3 and file4 on dev branch
* | fef775c change file3 and file4 on master branch
|/
* d8d81e6 add subfolder and it’s files
* 5446ea3  change file1
```

If you use `git subtree split` to split the `subfolder` to a new git repo, then only the commits which changed the `subfolder` (`file3` and `file4`) will show in the new repo commit history. The new repo commit history as below:

```
* 60a7f3e (master) change file3 for fourth time merge
*   954b730 Merge branch 'dev' into master
|\
| * b4b8d92 change file3 for second time merge
* |   35f7754 Merge branch 'dev' into matser
|\ \
| |/
| * fde1de3 change file3 and file4 on master branch
* | d4795a8 change file3 and file4 on master branch
|/
* cd367a2 add subfolder and it’s files
```

As you can see in the original repo:

- For the first commit `5446ea`, it only changed `file1` (out of `subfolder` directory), so the commit won’t show in the new repo.
- For the commit `5818123` need to merge for second time, since it also only changed `file1`, the commit won’t show in the new repo.
- For the commits (`b95668a`, `5d93766` and `ebdfb0b`) for third time merge, all of them are not changed the `subfolder`, so they won’t show in the new repo.
- For the commit `e1e054c`, it only changed `file2` on `dev` branch, so it won’t show in the new repo.
- For the fourth merged commit `8cb09fb`, it keep the `subfolder` (`file3` and `file4`) as the same version with it’s first parent commit `6e8ee57` (not changed subfolder) on `master` branch, so the commit also won’t show in new repo.